# Is is possible to get around zsh autocorrect for one specific argument?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

So, I''m testing out something and I have to run the same command repeatedly until it works. I'm doing something like this:

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.xml https://host.name
```

When I do that, zsh always replies with

```
zsh: correct '@filename.xml' to 'filename.xml' [nyae]? y
```

I want to get zsh to stop trying to autocorrect for only this command with only this argument. I eventually just made an alias in my .zshrc file and that solves the problem for me.

I'm just wondering if there is a *better* way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the word with `\` to avoid spelling correction:

```
curl -X POST -d \@filename.xml https://host.name
```